# Clear multiple react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a select:

```
<Select isClearable classNamePrefix="select" ref={myRef} menuPortalTarget={document.body} styles={style} placeholder="Select Foods" name="Foods" value={inputField.foods} options={options} onChange={event => handleInputChange2(index, event)} className="select selectNarrow">
```

And I have a button that is to clear all selects:

```
<IconButton size="small" aria-label="edit" onClick={() => handleRemoveFieldsAll(index)}><RemoveCircleIcon /></IconButton>
```

The function:

```
const handleRemoveFieldsAll = (index, event) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    setInputFields(INITIAL_STATE);
    values.splice(0);
    console.log(values);
  };
```

This works by removing and emptying the array, but the label of the select remains. How do I clear all remaining labels back to the placeholder?

Comment: can you add your code on `codesandbox`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

I have created two local states here. One for the options and the other for the selected option. Updating the state based on the button click and the same changes will reflect in the template.

```
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";

const opts = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(opts);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(opts[0]);
  const handleRemoveFieldsAll = (event) => {
    setSelected(null);
    setOptions([]);
  };

  const handleInputChange2 = (option) => {
    setSelected(option);
  };

  const handlePopulateFieldsAll = () => {
    setSelected(opts[0]);
    setOptions(opts);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Select
        isClearable
        classNamePrefix="select"
        // ref={myRef}
        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
        // styles={style}
        placeholder="Select Foods"
        name="Foods"
        value={selected}
        options={options}
        onChange={(event) => handleInputChange2(event)}
        className="select selectNarrow"
      ></Select>

      <IconButton
        size="small"
        aria-label="edit"
        onClick={() => handleRemoveFieldsAll()}
      >
        Reset all
      </IconButton>

      <IconButton
        size="small"
        aria-label="edit"
        onClick={() => handlePopulateFieldsAll()}
      >
        Populate all
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> CODESANDBOX - https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-moore-nn8w5?file=/src/App.js:0-1483

Let me know in case I am not covering your use case.

Comment: Looks like this will work in your case, I am trying to use myRef.current.select.clearValue() ... but this only clears the last select (there are multiple) rather than all. So I am effectively nulling the array but the placeholder still remains